# What's causing the content of our website to jump into place right after initial load?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Upon loading our website I am having some issues fixing the lower content snapping into place. Easier to see on a slower connection but it appears the content is *not* loading in the place its suppose to be. but loading lower than its suppose to be and then quickly moves into place.

Heres a link to a recording of what I am seeing via google chrome - cable speeds.

https://youtu.be/RgR0IyxiEvg

Thanks!

Comment: I can't for the life of me seem to reproduce the problem. On load, the page loads fairly quickly, there is a slight realignment of the logo and the content on the page (the products), but it's almost negligble, and not really anything you should worry about. I can't really see anything "snapping into place"?

Comment: Ill record it and send/post a link

Comment: https://youtu.be/RgR0IyxiEvg

Comment: Ah, that was what I meant with the realignment - that isn't really a problem, but okay, I can see how it might be annoying. Not entirely sure what's causing it, but I would assume it's because of resizing of the logo (and perhaps the other items). Have you done anything else to the page before the problems started? Updated the logo? Changed widths on containers or anything like that? I don't think the answers you've gotten has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Its kind of always done it and was one of those things i was just gana "Figure out later" but now its later and i cant figure it out. =/

Comment: You can turn on throttling under the "network" tab  in chrome dev tools to simulate slow connections

Comment: But how will that help me identify the problem?

Comment: I need some love in my CSS. Help me solve this. xD

Comment: Wow... I don't think it will be a simple solution, unfortunately. Your `<head>`-section for that webpage is over 200 lines. 200+ lines before you even get to the `<body>`-tag. There are so many things wrong with that site that... I don't even know where to start. (By wrong I mean the way it's coded, not necessarily how it works or displays).

Comment: I mean its a free wordpress theme with like 15 plugins + restyled.. what can i do to improve it?

Comment: I will be back for this question later; gotta go now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying to figure out what was wrong it was a simple render blocking issue. The height attribute for the banner was loading after the rest of the content.  So i had the elements above load in their css before the elements below. Which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class `ctaWrapper` on top. Upon scrolling you are adding a class `fixed` to it. That is causing the problem.

When the object is fixed, it goes out of the normal flow and gets the ability to stay on top of other objects.

In your case, the object on the top goes out of the flow and all the elements jump up a bit. Just add the class `fixed` to it. Because, I don't see the need to add fixed on scroll as the wrapper stays fixed all the time

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because it was doing that before I set ctaWrapper to a fixed position. Its been doing this over a month and I literally set ctaWrapper to a fixed position yesterday.

Comment: Would you like me to disable the fixed position/script and let u have a look?

Comment: Note: the issue is on load and the content below the header jumping into place on load. Not on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plug-in called "Simple Custom CSS and JS" which places your custom css and javascript inside your page's body tag, right after most of your content.

Which causes those css rules and javascript codes to be applied with a delay. Moving those from your page's body to head will solve the problem.

**Edit**:
Now I have checked the video you provided. It looks like the problem is about your image gallery. Before your gallery is loaded, your image(with "FRYD") has full(or auto?) width and height. When your image slider starts loading, it scales the image down to match the container's width(or height). You should consider doing this scaling with css in your page's head. most probably something like `max-width:100%;height:auto;` would be sufficient.

Comment: I moved the code - deactivated the plugin - However its still a problem and doing the same thing. 

-Thnx

Comment: I  had to revert my changes and re-activate the plugin because it broke our mobile menu for some reason so still have to figure that out. But seems the plugin is not the issue. Any other ideas?